# ReactJs,BootStrap,RouterDom

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-dom

Hello cannot under stand how its work with this import and routes i created a navbar , created couples of pages like videolectures , so i create a router (link) to the videolectures page but then i press from main page there is a navbar displayed on VideoLecture i get white screen and its nothing going on display NavBar is gone i also try to write some code inside a VideoLecture page but its still not going to dislpay anyway CodeBelow

NavBar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Navbar,Nav,Container} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Routes, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import logo from '../img/logo1.jpg';
import Videolectures from '../pages/videolectures'

export default function NavBar() {
    return(
      
      <div>
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
  <Container>
  <img
        src= { logo }
        width="35"
        height="35"
        className="d-inline-block align-top rounded-circle"
        alt = ""
        href= "#home"
      />
  <Navbar.Brand>React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="me-auto">
      <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/videolectures">VideoLectures</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Questions</Nav.Link>
    </Nav>
    <Nav>
      <Nav.Link href="#deets">Login</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
        Sing Up
      </Nav.Link>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Container>
</Navbar>

  <Routes>
    <Route path="/videolectures" element={<Videolectures/>}/>
  </Routes>
  </div>

    
    );
}
```

app.js

```
import NavBar  from './components/navbar';
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function App() {
  return ( 
    <NavBar/> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={ <App/> }>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

VideoLecture.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Card,Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default function Videolectures() {
    return(
        
        <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
  <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
      the card's content.
    </Card.Text>
    <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
        
    );
}
```

I also get messsage from web console

```
index.tsx:25 You rendered descendant <Routes> (or called `useRoutes()`) at "/" (under <Route path="/">) but the parent route path has no trailing "*". This means if you navigate deeper, the parent won't match anymore and therefore the child routes will never render.

Please change the parent <Route path="/"> to <Route path="*">.
warning @ index.tsx:25
index.tsx:25 No routes matched location "/videolectures"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the `BrowserRouter` initialization in the `App` component and add to it also the `/videolectures` Route.
Also change the `/` route element to `NavBar`:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<NavBar />}></Route>
        <Route path='/videolectures' element={<Videolectures />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Of course, you will need to change the `index.js` back to

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```